# Why do we need isometries in the completion of an incomplete metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

In Kreyszig's Introduction to Functional Analysis we find the following theorem.

> 1.6-2 Theorem (Completion). For a metric space $X = (X, d)$ there
>   exists a complete metric space $\hat X = (\hat X, \hat d)$ which has a subspace $W$ that is
>   isometric with $X$ and is dense in $\hat X$. This space $\hat X$ is unique except for
>   isometries.

I understand the theorem and its proof, but I wonder what the point is of the isometry between $W$ and $X$. Why can't the theorem e.g. be more simply put as

> For a metric space there exists a complete metric space $\hat X=(\hat X, \hat d)$ such that $X$ is a dense subspace of $W$.

Why do we need the isometry to find a completion of $X$ that is really only a completion of an isometric space of $X$? It seems overly complicated and somewhat random to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem overly complicated, but it's actually *easier*: for a metric space it usually doesn't matter what the underlying elements are. For example, if I tell you that I have a metric space with five elements, and I tell you that the metric $d$ satisfies $d(a, b) = 1 \iff a \neq b$, then you essentially already know what the metric space is. It no longer matters whether the elements are $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ or $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$ or $\{\text{red}, \text{orange}, \text{yellow}, \text{green}, \text{blue}\}$.

In a similar vein, the completion of the rational numbers (as a metric space) are the real numbers; however, in the usual construction of the rational numbers and the real numbers, it is not *technically* true that $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb R$. The rationals are usually equivalence classes of pairs of integers, while the real numbers -- including the real numbers that can be written as a quotient of two integers -- are some kind of infinite sets of rationals, or infinite sets of sequences of rationals. However, there is a subset of the real numbers that behaves exactly like the rationals, which is the image of the obvious inclusion $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$, so we usually identify the two sets.

Comment: Interesting answer, even more on perspective than just this particular question. So I should interpret two Isometric spaces more as being 'the same thing' than just 'a similar thing'

Comment: @QuestionMaker, absolutely! (Although you have to watch out with isometric spaces that can be "the same thing" in more than one way -- but save that for when you get to group theory..)

Answer (score 1):

The complication must lie somewhere. The space $\hat X$ defined by Kreyszig does *not* contain $X$ as a subset; it only contains a subspace $W$ isometric to $X$. So, after $\hat X$ has been defined, in otder to prove your simpler version of the thworem, one would have to consider the space $\tilde X=X\cup\left(\hat X\setminus W\right)$ and then define a metric on it. It can be done and it is not hard, be that new space $\tilde X$ is rather artificial then.

Comment: So if $X'$ is a completion of $X$ then I can find an isometry between $\tilde X$ and $X'\setminus X$ to translate the completion of $W$ back to $X$?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.